# Migrating to multi-site causing a redirect loop

Tags: multisite

I've got a huge single Wordpress site. Let's call it `example.com` with lots of plugins and loads of content.

I want to migrate this to be one of many sites in a **Wordpress Multisite** install.

My dev environment is `example.localhost` and my content is imported from live, and so the database contains `example.com`. Usually, my `wp-config.php` contains

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', "https://example.localhost" );
define( 'WP_HOME', "https://example.localhost" );
```

It's essential to be able to import content from live for testing to ensure that the dev environment is as close as possible to live, and I know it's *not a good idea* to do any munging of the database like replacing `example.com` with `example.localhost`

I've been messing around with Multisite on my local dev environment, and after running the config wizard, making the changes to `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess`, I was forced to log in. Unfortunately, on trying to log-in, I'm redirected to `example.com` and login does not work.

**wp-config.php**

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
...
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.localhost' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

How do I allow the site to continue using `example.localhost` on my local dev environment?

I don't want to do a find/replace on the URL in the database as this will likely break everything and isn't feasible to do whenever I import the site content.